# Consistency/Concurrency problems when using linux inoitfy

Tags: linux, rust, concurrency, inotify, consistency

I am working a project, which is to build a simple file synchronizer, using Rust language.

To monitor the changes in local files, I should use the linux utility `inotify`. However, when a new creation (file or directory) is detected, I should add new watches to the `inotify` instance, using the syscall `inotify_add_watch`.

Handling this using Rust seems simple, I can have an `inotify` instance and can add watches using `inotify.watches().add()`, read the events using `inotify.read_events_blocking()` functions.

However, I may want to **wait for events while adding new watches into the `inotify` instance**, and the adding operations may be handled on multi-threads (which is actually for the newly synchronized files to add watches for them. So I need the waiting for local changes at the same time).

I wonder, would there be conflicts in these scenarios :

- One thread is reading block the `inotify` instace, while another thread is adding a new watch.
- Multiple threads are trying to add different files' wathces at the same time.

By checking the linux man page, I got that all these operations are actually handled by the `inotify` instance's file descriptor, which means, all the operations above are using the same file descriptor. But I didn't find the man page saying there would be inconsistency problems.

And I also write a simple experiments to check the first senario

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut inotify = Inotify::init().unwrap();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
        loop {
            let events = inotify.read_events_blocking(buffer.as_mut()).unwrap();
            for event in events {
                println!("{:?}", event);
            }
        }
    });
    loop {
        // input a file path
        let mut file_path = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut file_path).unwrap();
        let file_path = file_path.trim();
        inotify.watches().add(file_path, *WATCH_EVENTS).unwrap();
        println!("watching {}", file_path);
    }
}
```

It works well, but I am still not sure about that.

If all the above oprations are atomic, here comes a new problem

Read events requires mutable reference to `inotify` instance

```rust
    pub fn read_events_blocking<'a>(&mut self, buffer: &'a mut [u8])
```

But adding a new watch should use the `Watch` interface, which is actually a private struct (I cannot have the interface in another thread)

```rust
    pub fn watches(&self) -> Watches {
        Watches::new(self.fd.clone())
    }
```

===============================updates==============================

At the version `0.10.0`, the interface `Watches` to add or remove watches is private, but I just found the at the latest version `0.10.2`, they made it public !

So I guess it totally safe to use that.

Comment: Would you mind adding an actual question to your question? :)

Comment: @Finomnis I have an actual question : look at the mid part, I gave two scenarios, and I wonder whether there would be concurrency problems in these two scenarios, that is, are these operations atomic ?

Comment: I'm afraid your question might be too convoluted to receive anwers ... Just as a heads up

Comment: @Finomnis Fine, as long as it works, there is no problem, lol